# Last element of li always change to specific after content

Tags: html, css, listitem

I make a list that contains a specific content, in this list with css I put a `+` when is the first `li` or middle element but if is the last I change the content with `=` in css.

I spect this: 
`1 + 2 + 3 = Result`
I obtain: `1 + 2 + 3 + Result`

My code:

```css
.list-look{
    padding-left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
ul li{
    list-style: none;
}
.list-look li.itemsLook{
    padding-right: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    width: 270px;
    position: relative;
  list-style: none;
}
ul li.itemsLook:not(:last-child)::before{
    speak: none;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 900;
    font-variant: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    content: "+";
    
    float: right;
    font-size: 35px;
    width: 10px;
    top: 25%;
    right: 15px;
  
}
ul li.itemsLook:last-child::before{
    content: "=";
   
    float: right;
    top: 25%;
    
}
```

```html
<ul class="list-look">
  <li class="itemsLook">1</li>
  <li class="itemsLook">2</li>
  <li class="itemsLook">3</li>
  <div>
    Result
  </div>
</ul>
```

Comment: Why Result is not in <li> with class "itemsLook" or else you need to change ul li.itemsLook:last-child::before to ul li.itemsLook:last-child::after

Comment: FYI, having a `div` as a child of a `ul` is invalid

Comment: LGSON yes, I know that is invalid but I put the element like this because I want that that div will be next to the last element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:last-child` looks for *any* element. You would want to use `:last-of-type` which will apply to the last `<li>` element in your example:

```css
.list-look{
    padding-left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
ul li{
    list-style: none;
}
.list-look li.itemsLook{
    padding-right: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    width: 4em;
    position: relative;
  list-style: none;
}
ul li.itemsLook:not(:last-of-type)::before{
    speak: none;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 900;
    font-variant: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    content: "+";
    
    float: right;
    font-size: 35px;
    width: 10px;
    top: 25%;
    right: 15px;
  
}
ul li.itemsLook:last-of-type::before{
    content: "=";
   
    float: right;
    top: 25%;
    
}
```

```html
<ul class="list-look">
  <li class="itemsLook">1</li>
  <li class="itemsLook">2</li>
  <li class="itemsLook">3</li>
  <div>
    Result
  </div>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your example does not work as you expected because you are misunderstanding how :last-child works. It does not work to change the last li.itemsLook element, it works on that element only if it is the last child of the ul (which it is not in this case because you have a div as the last child. https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_last-child.asp

One way around this might be to move the div out of the ul like so

```
<ul class="list-look">
  <li class="itemsLook">1</li>
  <li class="itemsLook">2</li>
  <li class="itemsLook">3</li>
</ul>
<div>
  Result
</div>
```

and then add `ul, div { display: inline}` to your CSS.